# Scala Currying Function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have two methods,  `nTimes` and `nTimesBetter`. Both functions perform an operation on a function passed as a parameter n times.

The method `nTimes` takes a function `f`, the number of times it has to be called `n` and the initial value for the function to work on `x`

```
def nTimes(f:Int=>Int,n:Int,x:Int):Int =
  if (n <= 0) x
  else
    nTimes(f, n-1, f(x))
```

The following is what happens when the method is called with some function `f`, `n = 3` and `x = 1`:

```
// nTimes(f,3,1)
// nTimes(f,2,f(1))
// nTimes(f,1,f(f(1)))
// nTimes(f,0,f(f(f(1))))
```

The method `nTimesBetter` method does not take initial value, but only a function `f` and the number of times `n` the function should be called

```
def nTimesBetter(f:Int=>Int,n:Int):(Int=>Int)=
  if (n <= 0) x => x
  else
   x => nTimesBetter(f, n-1)(f(x))
```

`nTimesBetter` returns a function that can be applied to an initial value

```
println(nTimes((x:Int)=>x+1,10,1))

val plus10 = nTimesBetter((x:Int)=>x+1,10)
println(plus10(1))
```

Can someone explain `nTimesBetter` with a stack of execution and use of `(x:Int) => nTimesBetter(f,n-1)(f(x))`? Why `(f(x))` is called like this.

Comment: side note: the easy way to write `nTimesBetter` when you already have `nTimes` is `def nTimesBetter(f: Int => Int, n: Int) = nTimes(f, n, _)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between these two is that the former returns a value and the latter returns a function `Int => Int`. The stack is far less readable than the one from `nTimes` but here it is:

```
  // nTimesBetter(f, 3)
  // x => nTimesBetter(f, 2)(f(x))
  // x => (x => nTimesBetter(f, 1)(f(x)))(f(x))
  // x => (x => (x => (x => x)(f(x)))(f(x)))(f(x))
```

> Why (f(x)) is called like this?

Because `nTimesBetter` returns a function that needs an argument. You can rewrite `nTimesBetter` as:

```
def nTimesBetter(f: Int => Int, n: Int): Int => Int =
  if (n <= 0) x => x
  else {
    val function: Int => Int = nTimesBetter(f, n - 1) // Creates a function
    x => function(f(x))                               // Uses f(x) as an argument
  }
```

PS. `nTimesBetter` is not that better because `nTimes` is tail recursive.

Comment: What will be sequence of execution of x => (x => (x => (x => x)(f(x)))(f(x)))(f(x)) ? Innermost expression will be evaluated first like stack function

Comment: Exactly. First `(x => x)(f(x))` will be evaluated to `f(x)`. Then we have `(x => f(x))(f(x))` which is `f(f(x))`. Finally we will get a function `x => f(f(f(x)))`.